# What's the relationship between hyperbola, hyperbolic functions and the exponential function?

Tags: complex-analysis, hyperbolic-functions

The hyperbolic functions can be expressed using the exponential function.

However how are these related to "hyperbolas"?

Comment: $x^2 - y^2 = 1$ is a hyperbola in the ordinary $x,y$ plane

Answer (score 1):

Consider $x=\cosh t$ and $y=\sinh t$.

For $t\in\mathbb R$, The coordinates $(x,y)$ trace the curve $x^2-y^2=1$, which is a *hyperbola*.

We sometimes call trig functions circular functions for a very similar reason. If $x=\cos t$ and $y=\sin t$, the coordinates $(x,y)$ trace a *circle*.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = cosh(t)$ and $y = sinh(t)$.  Then as $t$ varies, the point $(x,y)$ moves along the right branch of the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=1$.